# Proof that symmetries of a square form a group under composition

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am curious if there is less wonky/wordy way to prove that the eight symmetries of the square form a group under composition than by checking each property for each element.

I can prove this in a long and not-so-pretty way. But I would really love to see a better proof.

Thanks in advance, ladies and gents.

Comment: What about simply using a Cayley table?

Comment: @crash Associativity is tedious using Cayley tables, even on a small finite set.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers you have received?

Comment: Gerry - Yes! I'm sorry I forgot to accept an answer. I've just been incredibly busy lately. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, it is true that the set $S$ of symmetries of *any* geometrical object form a group under the operation, "followed by". For it is clear that "$a$ followed by ($b$ followed by $c$)" is the same as "($a$ followed by $b$) followed by $c$"; it is clear that "do nothing" is in $S$, and that for all $a$ in $S$, $a$ followed by "do nothing" and "do nothing" followed by $a$ are both the same as $a$; and it is clear that any symmetry that you can perform, you can undo, so there are inverses.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it what I wanted occurred to me after reading through your answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can regard each symmetry as a bijection from the vertices of the square to the vertices.  You then get associativity for free (function composition is associative).  Leaving the square in its original configuration is the identity.  Each motion can be reversed (geometrically this is clear: each flip (reflection) is its own inverse, and each rotation has a rotation of the same amount in the opposite direction as its inverse).

Comment: You might want to also observe we have closure since: rotation$\ast$rotation = rotation, rotation$\ast$flip = flip, flip$\ast$rotation = flip, and flip$\ast$flip = rotation, which is perhaps more fundamental than proving the existence of an identity and inverses. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A = \{\textbf{symmetries of a square}\}$

Observe that the $\textbf{8}$ symmetries are given by $R_0,R_{90},R_{180},R_{270},F_1,F_2,F_3,F_4$.

$F_i$ are flips either from mid edge to mid edge or from vertex to opposite vertex.

$R_j$ are the planar rotations and $R_0$ denotes the identity where you do nothing.

Now that the notation is set up make a square, label the vertices and verify the properties for $A$ to be a group. I say make a square since the geometry is easy to understand for a square and this will allow you to fill in the Cayley table in a matter or minutes.